# How to get errors indexed by validation group

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, validationgroup

I handle a multi-tab form that is validated by one group per form-tab. When I get errors while binding request, I'd like to know the first tab (ie validation group) that is not valid.

Is it possible with Symfony 2.0, and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible without hacking the core. The problem is that `Form` contains a references to `FormError` objects, which *do not keep* references to the original `ConstraintViolation` objects, which also do not keep references of the group under which the violation occurred.

I recommend to open a feature request ticket on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues).

Even if we added this feature, the problem would remain that a constraint is only evaluated *once* if it belongs to multiple groups that are validated at once. The violation would then only store the first group, even though it would have failed in the other groups too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! If the binding process loops on every constraints of each validation-group (but validate them only if not done yet), it must be possible to keep tracks on every failed group ?